# Contact form 7 (Wordpress plugin)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use contact form 7. When I put the shortcode in the page and try to use the form, no action will happen. What should I do ?

Comment: wat do you mean by no action? isn't the form showing, or doesn't it get submitted?

Comment: It doesn't get submitted.

Comment: No. Nothing is showen.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate other plugins...  This error happen to me.

Comment: It doesn't work. I deactivate all other plugins except contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

Download fiddler and see if anything is getting posted, if it isn't then check the browser console to see if there are any js errors, If you have custom JS on the page can almost guarantee it is breaking on that and not running the CF7 Scripts